# Newbie help required understanding image file loading Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I have been given a JS file handler which is triggered via an event that comes off a HTML

I have been going through the code and adding comments above lines of code as I understand each section. However I am stumped again and need some help. I have been using the Mozilla Devepment Network site as a reference and have included links were needed.

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {  
    // event.target is the object the event was dispatched on http://mzl.la/1ao1BI7
    // which is document.getElementById('file')
    var file = evt.target.files[0];  
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(fileObject) {
    //  result attribute contains the data as a URL representing the file's data as a base64 encoded string.
    var data = fileObject.target.result;
    console.log(fileObject.type);

    // Create an image object
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
      window.imageSrc = this;
      // clear the input once image is loaded
      input1.value= "";
      input2.value= "";
      redrawMeme(window.imageSrc, null, null);
    }

    // Set image data to background image.
    image.src = data;        
  };
  // Call the reader.onload function with var file = evt.target.files[0];
  // Contains  the data as a URL representing the file's data as a base64 encoded string.
  // this line triggers the loading of the file
  // contents of thefile isstores in reader.result
  reader.readAsDataURL(file)
}
```

This is the line I dont get:

```
reader.onload = function(fileObject)
```

Where does fileObject come from and what is its structure? Can you also included a link to relevent page on the MDN site please. I can understand that `reader.onload` is triggered once the file has finished loading and that the function next to it on the same line is executed. This implies that `reader.onload` returned something and this was passed into the function. Then the next line after that `var data = fileObject.target.result` reveals the structure of this object, but what type is this object? Where can I find it in the MDN?

Answer (score 0):

`fileObject` is the event object. So the Event (load) is passed to the `onload` event. When onload fires the code can access the files from the event. Ergo `fileObject` is a reference to the event. If you request the type it will be a `load event`.

The onload event fires as soon as `readAsDataURL(file)` has finished loading. But is needs to know the outcome of the read. That is stored in the event, here referenced as `fileObject`. The target of the event is the 'reader' and that now contains a `result` ergo the `data url` in base64.

What happens inside the fileReader:

- the fileReader loads the file retrieved from the event `evt.target.files[0]`, either by a `drag-drop-handler` or by selecting an file from a file input handler.
- Parses it content into a base64 encoded string
- That string is returned as a `data-url` in the `result`.

FileReader acts as a `man in the middle` in this case. It shields the users data from abuse while providing the programmer with valuable information about the file needed to make website programming more robust.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: That's a bit too simplistic. How does fileObject.target.result differ from evt.target.files[0] used in the second line of code then? According to the MDN pages when the file finishes loading the data is stored in reader.result so why not get it form there?

Comment: @ImranNazir `evt.target.files[0]` belongs to the file input. This event is fired upon selecting a file. You cannot access file information about this file from that input (for obvious security reasons). The file from the event is passed into the filereader which fires an `onload` (with it's own event). This event refers to the `filereader` via `event.target`. Since the file is loaded, you can now access certain properties of the file. Also the file has been copied into a data-url in `event.target.result`